# Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.5.3) when i run my deploy.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity

This is where the error starts in my deploy script

```
        // create VRFV2 Subscription
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait()
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
```

and this is my constructor

```
    address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint256 interval,
        uint256 entranceFee, 
        uint32 callbackGasLimit
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_interval = interval;
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    }
```

i try to use getContract instead of getContractAt and i get another error **getContract** is not a function

Comment: You should have to use getContract for referencing deployed contracts..   getContractAt requires name, deployed address & signers as params.. refer https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers#helpers

Comment: Yes but when i use getContract i get an error getContract is not a function, and i don't know how to solve for that error

Comment: If you are importing ethers like  ..   const { ethers } = require("ethers")  , please comment it .    To use getContract you have to use hardhat ethers..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So i realize this problem is more common than i thought and i found so many people asking for thesame work around here on stack overflow but not so many answers, so i hope this directs others on how to fix this.
Note: If you're getting an error message **Type Err: getContract is not a function** from your deploy script then this is for you.
Apparently this is a hardhat-waffle related problem and this following the instructions on [this link](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy-ethers/issues/12). The issue that getContract is not recognized as a valid function and Fabianschu explains it in the best fashion.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've tried a lot stuff, this solved my issue;

module.exports --> should be imported like this `import { something } from "somewhere"`

export default --> should be imported like this `import something from "somewhere"`

Please attention to curly braces are existing or not!